# Rails: Show data from 2 tables in "collection_select"

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, html-select

I have two models:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :active, :title, :url_name

  has_many :category_images
end

class CategoryColor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

In the **categories** table is a list of categories, in **category_colors** is list of added colors for a category.

I want to display in the **collection_select** all categories, that have in the table **category_colors** some colors. How to do that?

So far, I am able to only list all categories in the select tag:

```
= collection_select(:item, :chosen_category, Category.order('categories.title ASC'), :id, :title, prompt: true)
```

Thank you very much for an advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've achieve that this way:

```
= collection_select(:item, :chosen_category, @category_colors.map(&:category), :id, :title, prompt: true)
```

and in the controller for this action:

```
@category_colors = CategoryColor.group('category_id')
```

Voila!

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps

```
<%= collection_select(:categorycolor, :categoty_id, Category.order('categories.title ASC'), :id, :title, prompt: true) %>
```